# SecureGroovyScript.script expect class java.lang.String but received SecureGroovyScript

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a jenkinsfile which allows the dynamic parameters, using the SecureGroovyScript and CascadeChoiceParameter. Here is my code

```
properties([
    parameters([
        choice(choices: "\nDev" + "\nQA" + "\nStage" +"\nProd",description: 'Please select an environment',name: 'Env'), 
        [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', 
            description: 'Select the Server from the Dropdown List', 
            filterLength: 25, 
            filterable: true, 
            name: 'Server', 
            referencedParameters: 'Env', 
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                fallbackScript: [
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: 
                        'return[\'Could not get Environment from Env Param\']'
                ], 
                script: [
                    sandbox: false, 
                    script: new SecureGroovyScript(''' if (Env.equals("Dev"))
                    {
                        return["Dev1","Dev2","Dev3","Dev4"]
                    }
                    else if(Env.equals("QA")){
                        return["QA1","QA2","QA3"]
                    }
                    else if(Env.equals("Stage")){
                        return["Stg1","Stg2","Stg3"]
                    }
                    else if(Env.equals("Prod")){
                        return["Prod1","Prod2"]
                    }''',false,[])
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])
```

When I execute the code, it kept showing the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript.script expects class java.lang.String but received class org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:421)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:341)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:282)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {sandbox=false, script=org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SecureGroovyScript@69525ebd} for SecureGroovyScript(script: String, sandbox: boolean, classpath: ClasspathEntry(path: String)[])
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:287)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:403)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:341)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:282)
```

I doubted that the problem originated from the instantiation of SecureGroovyScript which recognizes the input script in the wrong way. Is there any way to work around this?

---UPDATE---
Thanks, @metalisticpain for your advice. I have some more additional comment.
what I want to achieve is to read file from the path dynamically chosen. here is what I tried but still not succeded

```
                    script: 
                    '''
                    if (!Env.isEmpty()){
                        GString path = "converge-cloud-params/${Env}-flavors.txt"
                        File file = new File(path)
                        result = file.readLines()
                        return result
                    }
                    '''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try just do what it says so instead of

```
                script: new SecureGroovyScript(''' if (Env.equals("Dev"))
                {
                    return["Dev1","Dev2","Dev3","Dev4"]
                }
                else if(Env.equals("QA")){
                    return["QA1","QA2","QA3"]
                }
                else if(Env.equals("Stage")){
                    return["Stg1","Stg2","Stg3"]
                }
                else if(Env.equals("Prod")){
                    return["Prod1","Prod2"]
                }''',false,[])
```

do

```
                script: (''' if (Env.equals("Dev"))
                {
                    return["Dev1","Dev2","Dev3","Dev4"]
                }
                else if(Env.equals("QA")){
                    return["QA1","QA2","QA3"]
                }
                else if(Env.equals("Stage")){
                    return["Stg1","Stg2","Stg3"]
                }
                else if(Env.equals("Prod")){
                    return["Prod1","Prod2"]
                }''',false,[])
```

Remove the new SecureGroovyScript because its probably expecting a string and will process it for you.

for a dynamic contents, try

```
        script: ("""
                if (!Env.isEmpty()){
                    return readFile file:'converge-cloud-params/${Env}-flavors.txt'
                }
                """
```

see https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace for reference.

Comment: i've tried remove this and it works. however another problem prompted. I want to read text file from this script but i tried something like `return[readFile("pathToFile")]` but it just did not work. could you please help me with it again?

Comment: I would read the file seperate and this pass it in. Swap all the quotes from ' -> " and from " -> '
Then plug in the variable as a GString `${file_contents}`

Comment: I have updated my question as it's not enough to specify the problem inside a comment. It would be much appreciated to have your advice once again. Thank you!

Comment: try the last bit